# PowerShell Select-String option

Tags: powershell-2.0

Using the `Select-String` cmdlet:

```
Get-Content C:\Temp\PatchVerify\$env:ComputerName.csv | Select-String "UNKNOWN" -quiet
```

Once all "Unknown" strings are found what options can I add to delete those strings?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do what I think you're trying to then try this code:

```
$file = Get-Content "C:\Temp\PatchVerify\$env:ComputerName.csv" | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "UNKNOWN",""}

Set-Content C:\Temp\test.txt "C:\Temp\PatchVerify\$env:ComputerName.csv"
```

1. Get the content of your file as a variable
2. Pipe the output to a replace operator for each occurrence of the "UNKNOWN" string
3. Assign the result to a variable
4. Use the Set-Content cmdlet to save the variable as your new file